# Check if URL has protocol http(s) if not add one with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if URL has a protocol or not, for example

```
<a id ="link1" href="www.example.com"></a>
<a id="link2" href="http://www.example.com"></a>
<a id="link3" href="https://www.example.com"></a>
```

I want to first check if URL has a protocol or not and if href doesn't contain protocol I want to add `//`.

So for examaple for the first url would be:

```
<a href="//www.example.com"></a>
```

This is my code

```js
var url = document.getElementById("link1");
for(var i=0; i<url.length; i++) {
  $('#link1').append(urls[i].replace(/\/?(\?|#|$)/, '/$1'));
}
```

```html
 <a id="link" href="www.example.com" ></a>
```

Can somebody try to help me with this?

Comment: IDs must be unique

Comment: `document.getElementById("link1")` doesn't have a `.length` property / there's no `urls` variable - please review the snippet to ensure it runs and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I updated my answer so you can choose what // or https:// you want

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this

Change

```
 hrefAttr = new URL("https://"+hrefAttr)
```

to

```
 hrefAttr = new URL("//"+hrefAttr)
```

or

```
 hrefAttr = new URL(location.protocol+"//"+hrefAttr)
```

to match your wishes

```js
$(".link").each(function() {
  let hrefAttr = $(this).attr("href");
  const host = "www.example.com"; // location.host; on your server
  if (hrefAttr != $(this).prop("href")) {
    try {
      url = new URL(hrefAttr)
    }
    catch(e) { 
      if (e.message.toLowerCase().includes("invalid") && 
          hrefAttr.includes(host)) { // test that the page host is not in the URL (handles /page.html for example
        hrefAttr = new URL("https://"+hrefAttr)
        console.log(hrefAttr)
        $(this).prop("href",hrefAttr);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link" href="www.example.com">Change this</a><br/>
<a class="link" href="/page2.html">Do not change this (page)</a><br/>
<a class="link" href="http://www.example.com">Do not change this full url</a><br/>
<a class="link" href="https://www.example.com">Do not change this full url</a><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function(){
  const urls = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for(let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
    let href = urls.item(i).getAttribute("href");
    if(typeof href == "string" && href != "" && href.substr(0, 4) != "http"){
      urls.item(i).setAttribute("href", "//" + href);
    }
    
    // only for demo
    urls.item(i).innerHTML = urls.item(i).innerHTML + " (" + href + ")";
  }
})();
```

```css
a{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a id="link1" href="www.example.com" >Link 1</a>
<a id="link2" href="http://www.example.com" >Link 2</a>
<a id="link3" href="https://www.example.com" >Link 3</a>
```

Comment: Cool, if there is a way to remove this // from content so the url looks like this: <a id="link1" href="//www.example.com">Link 1 (www.example.com)</a>

Comment: @mplungjan Yes. That's intendet. This is what the OP wants: "[I]f href doesn't contain [a] protocol I want to add `//`". "/page1.html" doesn't contain a protocol, so I add `//`.

Comment: @IvanNukleus I changed my answer so the `//` is still present in the `href` but not in the content. The `a` tag is then `<a id="link1" href="//www.example.com">Link 1 (www.example.com)</a>` what you are requesting.

Comment: @miile7 Obviously OP did not consider internal links.

Comment: @mplungjan Hmm. Your interpretation. Anyway it's not hard to change. Simply add `href.substr(0, 1) != "/"` (or `href.match(/^\s*\//)` for ignoring whitespace) to the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Just retrieve all the anchor elements you want to check using the `querySelectorAll()` method (make sure you change your anchor `id` attribute to `class` since duplicate IDs are not allowed), then use the [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to check if the url contains `://` or starts with a character like say, `/` and if it doesn't, append the `//` to the beginning of the URL like this:

```js
const urls = document.querySelectorAll(".link");

[...urls].map(url => {
  let x = url.getAttribute("href");
  
  if(!x.includes("://") && !x.startsWith("/")) {
    url.href = "//" + x;
  }
})
```

```html
<a class ="link" href="www.example.com">A</a>
<a class="link" href="http://www.example.com">B</a>
<a class="link" href="https://www.example.com">C</a>
<a class="link" href="/page2.html">D</a>
```